# Getting "Aw! Snap" issue in Execution of Selenium Automation Suite in Chrome

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using google chrome driver to automate using selenium. Chrome window always gets crashed in middle of execution when I try to navigate to some other URL. Please note that I get this error only when I try to navigate to same url for the 15th times i.e it works fine till 14th. I am done with upgrading/degrading chrome web driver.

Details:
 os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_171'
ChromeDriver 2.38.552522 (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb) on port 9319
[image]

**Update: Guys, I do not get same issue when I create separate instance of chrome driver for each time when I navigate to URL.**

Comment: whcih chrome version you are using

Comment: @AnkurSingh I am using "Version 66.0.3359.139 (Official Build) (64-bit)"

Comment: @Raj Your code trials please

Comment: Hi @DebanjanB , I won't be able to share code because of privacy issue (Strict warning given by management). Additionally you won't be able to access url from your system.
I have just written "driver.navigate().to(mainurl)" and call the same for multiple times. During 15th times, It sshows "Loading" status for more than usual time which later leads to "Aw Snap" error

Comment: Did you try clearing your cookies and cache everytime you iterate over your workflow? Chrome is known to use a lot of ram over extended period of usage. Or cookies/cache from previous iteration is causing the page to crash. Info on how to do this can be found on this blog https://intoli.com/blog/clear-the-chrome-browser-cache/

Comment: @GPT14 Actually I created new instance for everytime I iterate  and issue has been fixed now. So yeah this might be issue. Thanks :)