# Selenium Headless Chrome Driver Throwing Oh Snap Error

Tags: python, selenium

I saw the other threads regarding this issue but none of them work, and they are usually targeting Mac or Linux, but I am on **Windows**

Anyway, I am trying to create a scraper which goes through posts on Facebook Group and get them back. The scraper works perfectly when the number of posts are around 500-600 or less. However, the client is trying to use it on 1k posts and it receives "Oh Snap error) (On our PCs which use Windows 10-11)

```
# Start Selenium Imports
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import  Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
# Selenium Imports Finished
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
from datetime import date, timedelta, datetime
import re, json, time

creds = {}
posts = []
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument("--window-size=1200,800")
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
options.add_argument("--enable-javascript")
options.add_argument('--disable-application-cache')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')        
options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64; rv:103.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/103.0')

driver=webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),options=options)
actions = ActionChains(driver)
    
#-----------------Open Credentials----------------------------#
def openCredentials():
    with open('credentials.json') as file:
        return json.load(file)
#-----------------End-----------------------------------------#

#-----------------Login to facebook.com using ID of email Input box, password & loginBtn-------#
def login(email, password):
    driver.get('https://www.facebook.com/login/')
    #Email
    driver.find_element(By.ID,'email_container').find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'input').send_keys(email)
    #Password
    driver.find_element(By.ID,'pass').send_keys(password)
    #Enter 
    driver.find_element(By.ID, 'loginbutton').click()
# Finish login to facebook.com

#-----------------Check Date of the last post in page---------#
def checkDate(date):
    main_div=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@role='feed']")
    posts = main_div.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".g4tp4svg.mfclru0v.om3e55n1.p8bdhjjv")
    last_date = ""
    
    
    while True: 
        try:
            last_date = posts[len(posts)-1].find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,".gvxzyvdx.aeinzg81.t7p7dqev.gh25dzvf.exr7barw.b6ax4al1.gem102v4.ncib64c9.mrvwc6qr.sx8pxkcf.f597kf1v.cpcgwwas.f5mw3jnl.szxhu1pg.nfkogyam.kkmhubc1.tes86rjd.rtxb060y.ztn2w49o").find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "a")
            break
        except:
            return False

    if "at" in last_date.text:
        last_date = last_date.text.split('at')[0].strip()
    else:
        last_date = last_date.text
    
    print(f"Current last post's date {(datetime.strptime(convertDate(last_date), '%B %d')).strftime('%B %d')}")
    
    return date.lower() in(datetime.strptime(convertDate(last_date), "%B %d")).strftime("%B %d").strip().lower()
#-----------------End-----------------------------------------#

#-----------------Reach a specific number of posts in page----#
def reachPosts(noOfPosts = 50) -> None:
    posts = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@role='feed']").find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".g4tp4svg.mfclru0v.om3e55n1.p8bdhjjv")
    
    postsNo = len(posts) 
    posts = None
    while  postsNo < noOfPosts+1:
        scroll_down()
        posts = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@role='feed']").find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".g4tp4svg.mfclru0v.om3e55n1.p8bdhjjv")
        time.sleep(1)
        print(len(posts))
        postsNo = len(posts)
        posts = None
    
    posts = None
        
#----------------End------------------------------------------#

#----------------Scroll Function!-----------------------------#
def scroll_down():
    """A method for scrolling the page."""

    # Scroll down to the bottom.
    #driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

    time.sleep(2.5)

#-----------------End-----------------------------------------#

#-----------------Date Conversion Function--------------------#
def convertDate(inputDate):
    if inputDate is not None and inputDate != "":
        if "hrs" in inputDate.lower() or "mins" in inputDate.lower() or ("m" in inputDate and len(inputDate) > 1 and len(inputDate) < 4) or ("h" in inputDate and "march" not in inputDate.lower()): #For example, the date is '6 hrs', so convert it to today's date
            return (date.today()).strftime("%B %d")

        if "d" in inputDate[1].lower(): # For example, date is '2d' which means 2 days back from now, so today's date - 2 days.
            days = int(inputDate[0])
            return (date.today() - timedelta(days=days)).strftime("%B %d")
        
        if "yesterday" in inputDate.lower():
            return (date.today() - timedelta(days=1)).strftime("%B %d") 
    else:
        return (date.today()).strftime("%B %d")
    
    try: 
        return (datetime.strptime(inputDate, "%d %B")).strftime("%B %d")
    except:
        return inputDate
#-----------------End-----------------------------------------#

def seeMore(postDiv):
    """ 
        It checks if the 'See more' exists in the post, and press on it. 
    """
    try:
            seemorebutton=postDiv.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[contains(text(),'See more')]")
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", seemorebutton)
    except:
            pass 

#-----------------Getting Text of post-----------------------------------------#
def postText(postDiv):
    text=postDiv.find('div',{'data-ad-preview':'message'})
    
    if text is None:
        text=postDiv.find('div', {'class': 'i85zmo3j alzwoclg cqf1kptm pytsy3co jcxyg2ei s8sjc6am myo4itp8 ekq1a7f9 mfclru0v'})
        if text is None:
            text = postDiv.find('div', {'class': 'm8h3af8h l7ghb35v kjdc1dyq kmwttqpk gh25dzvf'})
    
    try:
        return text.text
    except:
        return None
#-----------------End-----------------------------------------#

def scrapGroup(facebookUrl, inputDate):
    driver.get(f'{facebookUrl}?sorting_setting=CHRONOLOGICAL')
    time.sleep(1)
    
    # Check Either reach a specific date or number of posts
    if inputDate == "":
        reachPosts(creds["Number of posts"])
    else:     
        print(f'Scraping till {convertDate(inputDate)}')
        while not checkDate(convertDate(inputDate)): 
            scroll_down()
            time.sleep(2)
    
    # Scraping the posts
    
    posts = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@role='feed']").find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".g4tp4svg.mfclru0v.om3e55n1.p8bdhjjv")
    header = ['facebook_group_url','facebook_post_urls','Date','text_per_post','comment_and_time','Comment URL','Date of Scraping']
    file = open(f'{driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h1.jxuftiz4.jwegzro5.hl4rid49.icdlwmnq.gvxzyvdx.aeinzg81").text}-{date.today()}.csv', 'w', encoding='UTF8', newline='')
    writer = csv.writer(file)

    # write the header
    writer.writerow(header)

    noOfPosts = 0 
    
    if creds["Date"] != "" and creds["Date"] is not None:
        noOfPosts = len(posts)
    else:
        noOfPosts = creds["Number of posts"]
    
    posts = None
    
    for i in range(0, noOfPosts, 50):
        posts = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@role='feed']").find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".g4tp4svg.mfclru0v.om3e55n1.p8bdhjjv")[i:i+50]
        
        for j in range(0,len(posts)):
                time_dict=[]
                comment_list=[]
                data_list=[]     
                print(f"Scraping Post {i+j+1}")
                singlePostDiv=posts[j].find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "icdlwmnq")
                
                for k in range(4):
                    seeMore(singlePostDiv)
                        
                # Open all comments.
                # TODO: change to functino 
                try:
                    classText = singlePostDiv.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//span[@class="alzwoclg lxowtz8q aeinzg81"]')
                    for b in classText:
                                # print(b.text)
                                if "comment" in b.text or "answers" in b.text:
                                    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", b)
                    time.sleep(4)
                except:
                    pass
                
                #    ..........FIND SOUP ALL PAGE..............
                html=singlePostDiv.get_attribute('innerHTML')
                soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
                
                # ..........Post Text & Time..........#        
                text = postText(soup)
                timeLinkEl =soup.find('a',{'class':'qi72231t nu7423ey n3hqoq4p r86q59rh b3qcqh3k fq87ekyn bdao358l fsf7x5fv rse6dlih s5oniofx m8h3af8h l7ghb35v kjdc1dyq kmwttqpk srn514ro oxkhqvkx rl78xhln nch0832m cr00lzj9 rn8ck1ys s3jn8y49 icdlwmnq jxuftiz4 cxfqmxzd tes86rjd'})
                postTime = timeLinkEl.get('aria-label')
                #-----------End-----------------------#
                
                # ..............FIND ALL COMMENTS ................
                all_comments=soup.find_all('div',{'class':'jg3vgc78 cgu29s5g lq84ybu9 hf30pyar r227ecj6'})
                if len(all_comments)>0:
                    for comment in all_comments:
                            try:
                                comment =  comment.find('div', {'class':"d2hqwtrz o9wcebwi b6ax4al1"})
                                commentText = comment.text
                                tagged = comment.find('a').text.strip()
                                if tagged != None:
                                    commentText.replace(tagged, 'A user said ')
                                time_dict.append(
                                    {
                                    "Comment":commentText,    
                                    "Date": comment.find_all('li')[-1].text
                                    }
                                ) 
                                if comment.find('img'):
                                        comment_image_url=comment.find('img').get('src')
                                else:
                                    comment_image_url="No Image "        
                            except:
                                time_dict.append({
                                    "Comment": "No Comment",
                                    "Date": "No Time"
                                })
                                comment_image_url="No Image"
        
                else:
                    time_dict.append({
                        "Comment": "No Comment",
                        "Date": "No Time"
                    })
                    comment_image_url="No Image"

                writer.writerow([creds['Facebook Groups'][0], timeLinkEl.get('href'), convertDate(postTime), text, time_dict, comment_image_url, date.today()])


def main():
    global creds
    creds = openCredentials()
    
    login(creds["email"], creds["password"])
    
    time.sleep(3)
    
    for group in creds['Facebook Groups']:
        scrapGroup(group, creds["Date"])
        time.sleep(3)


main()
```

The code is simple, the error happens when the crawler finishes scrolling and starts going into scraping each post on its own (When it enters the loop)

I have tried everything I can find online and still no luck.

Thanks in advance. (Laptop is 16 GB Ram)

And the error that is thrown on my terminal
`ERROR:v8_initializer.cc(714)] V8 javascript OOM (Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit).`

Comment: ""Oh Snap error)" What does this mean? Please read [ask] and make sure to show a [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error message, by copying and pasting, starting from the line that says `Traceback (most recent call last):` until the end and formatting it like multi-line code. Also please try to create a [mre] - what parts of the code are actually *necessary* to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Chrome Error page which says "Oh Snap, something went wrong" 

Also, there no traceback, as the code didn't raise an exception, the Selenium Webdriver had the error and not python itself, so that's the only line of error I have

Comment: So, that is **the web page** telling you that there is a problem, not the code. Maybe this is because the people who operate the web page **do not want you** to be able to use the scraper on 1k posts at a time?

Comment: This is an issue in Chrome Webdriver, neither the webpage nor the code, similar to the issue described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50327489/getting-aw-snap-issue-in-execution-of-selenium-automation-suite-in-chrome